# PyCharm go to actual implementation and not stubs

Tags: pycharm

With given code below i would like to navigate to implementation of Pool method in PyCharm.

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes_count, *args, **kwargs)
```

Using option to navigate to either Declaration or Implementation navigates me directly to: JetBrains/PyCharm 2019.1.3/helpers/typeshed/stdlib/3/multiprocessing/**init**.pyi

Instead to:
Python/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py

How would you navigate directly to implementation without jumping through folders to find way in?

Comment: The reason is that PyCharm unable to find declaration of `Pool` in `Python/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py` but able to find it in stub